# wiping out a datomic db for test environment ?

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'm trying to truncate my dataomic database between tests. I see a lot of questions on google about excision and how to delete data, but none about just wiping a database clean.

I'm doing something along the following using core.test:

```
(with-redefs [db/uri  "datomic:free://localhost:4334/test_om_asyn101_next"
              db/conn (d/connect db/uri)]
  (run-tests 'rtest.core-test))
```

I've been wiping out the DB by changing the URI and creating anew, but getting tired of doing that! Thanks!

Comment: Does "Between tests" mean during unit testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [delete-database](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/index.html#datomic.api/delete-database) fn. See [day of datomic](https://github.com/Datomic/day-of-datomic/blob/master/src/datomic/samples/repl.clj#L21) tutorial for an example about how to create a new in memory db for each test.

Also, [yeller](http://yellerapp.com/posts/2014-05-07-testing-datomic.html) has a nice example of how to use [datomic's "what if"](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/with) functionality to do unit testing.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using `(delete-database)` as dAni suggests, with a clojure.test fixture:

```
(ns test-util)
(defn datomic-rollback-fixture [test-fn]
  ;; setup
  (run-migrations)
  ;; run the tests
  (test-fn)
  ;; clean up
  (let [datomic-uri (get-in config/config [:datomic :uri])]
    (when (string/starts-with? datomic-uri "datomic:mem:")
      (d/delete-database datomic-uri))))
```

The `(run-migrations)` function loads our schema definitions from an EDN file, which we have defined via [conformity](https://github.com/rkneufeld/conformity). The bit about only destroying a `datomic:mem` database is because I'm paranoid about deleting databases out of production by accident.

Then in the test functions, we've got:

```
(use-fixtures :each test-util/datomic-rollback-fixture)

(deftest my-test ...)
```

Seems to work fine for me so far and is plenty fast enough with the memory database.

Comment: Such paranoia can be put to rest by having your tests in a test-classpath only, therefore never ending up in the jar you ship to production. Leiningen can do that for you.

Comment: Spoken like someone who isn't paranoid enough. ;)